# Rserve connection from local R client to Rserve host on AWS Server

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rserve

Currently trying to connect to an Amazon AWS server via IP address on port 6311. I've set up Rserve as a daemon on the AWS server and have checked that it is in fact listening on port 6311 by calling the netstat command, but when I run the follow from my local R client:

```
c <- RS.connect(host = "x.x.x.x")
```

I get this error message:

```
-  cannot connect to x.x.x.x:6311
```

The local client does have RSClient installed, we've verified that Rserve is installed and running correctly on the host server.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to connect to a remote server using this method??

Comment: Can you confirm that you added an appropriate rule to allow inbound access to 6311 in your AWS security groups? (eg http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html )

Comment: If you have nmap installed on a client, what does `nmap -p 6311 x.x.x.x` return?

Comment: I can confirm that I've added an inbound TCP connection on 6311 to my security group in amazon.

Nmap states that 6311 is currently open

Comment: Could you add the output of `R CMD Rserve --RS-settings` from the server?

Comment: Here's the response:

config file: /etc/Rserv.conf
working root: /tmp/Rserv
port: 6311
local socket: [none, TCP/IP used]
authorization required: no
plain text password: not allowed
passwords file: [none]
allow I/O: yes
allow remote access: yes
control commands: no
interactive: yes
max.input buffer size: 262144 kB

Comment: I can connect to an Rserve server from a client using RSclient and the same settings you use. Does `telnet x.x.x.x 6311` from the client return `Rsrv0103QAP1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the entire public dns address as your host.

(e.g.)

```
c <- RS.connect(host = "ec2-X-X-X-X.{availability_zone}.compute.amazonaws.com")
```